# IMAP command - Create a MIME message

Tags: email, imap

I'm wondering what is the `IMAP` command to create a multi-part `\Draft` message? and how does it work? Thanks

Comment: I've tried a simple message `A003 APPEND saved-messages (\Draft) {11}` `hello world` however, keep getting `NO [TRYCREATE] Folder doesn't exist. (Failure)`

Comment: first action is creating message, then setting a flag as it is shown in link of my answer

Comment: It's telling you that you're trying to `APPEND` to a folder that you haven't created yet.  Either `APPEND` to `INBOX` or do a `A001 CREATE saved-messages` first.

Comment: @Yuriy: No, that's not necessary.  The IMAP protocol absolutely allows you to specify flags when creating a message via `APPEND`, and some IMAP servers will not allow you to set or unset the `\Draft` flag on an existing message.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do, is create a MIME message. The IMAP protocol doesn't do this for you. MIME messages are their own RFC. Most SMTP components (software) will create a MIME message (they have to, for sending over SMTP), and allow you to get access to the MIME message.  Once you have the source of the MIME message (usually as a string), you then upload (APPEND) the MIME message to the Draft folder.

You then set the \Draft flag on that message.

Comment: He's actually got the `APPEND` command syntax right, including the `\Draft` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that it is stored in folder "Draft"?
just a copy of email, that was created. It is not sent, but available in folder

About flags:

[look at this](http://docs.racket-lang.org/net/imap.html#%28def._%28%28lib._net/imap..rkt%29._imap-flag-~3esymbol%29%29)

Comment: I mean a message that does not exist yet in any folder, but needs to be created and stored with the \Draft flag in some particular folder.

Comment: http://docs.racket-lang.org/net/imap.html#(def._((lib._net/imap..rkt)._imap-flag-~3esymbol))